# What are the expected values in the input in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch, following [the tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/intro.html). I want to implement a regresor for a nonlinear function with 4 real inputs and 2 real outputs. I cannot find anywhere what is the supposed range for the inputs and outputs. They should go between -1 and 1? Between 0 and 1? Can it be anything?

### More details

I have written the following simple parameterized model for experimenting:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs: int, n_outputs: int, n_hidden_layers: int, n_nodes_per_hidden_layer: int):
        n_inputs = int(n_inputs)
        n_outputs = int(n_outputs)
        n_hidden_layers = int(n_hidden_layers)
        n_nodes_per_hidden_layer = int(n_nodes_per_hidden_layer)
        if any([i<=0 for i in [n_inputs,n_outputs,n_hidden_layers,n_nodes_per_hidden_layer]]):
            raise ValueError(f'All n_inputs, n_outputs, n_hidden_layers and n_nodes_per_hidden_layer must be greater than 0.')
        super().__init__()
        self.input_layer = torch.nn.Linear(n_inputs, n_nodes_per_hidden_layer)
        self.hidden_layers = [torch.nn.Linear(n_nodes_per_hidden_layer, n_nodes_per_hidden_layer) for i in range(n_hidden_layers)]
        self.output_layer = torch.nn.Linear(n_nodes_per_hidden_layer, n_outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x *= .1
        activation_function = torch.nn.functional.relu
        x = activation_function(self.input_layer(x))
        for idx,layer in enumerate(self.hidden_layers):
            x = activation_function(layer(x))
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x
```

and I instantiate it in this way:

```
dnn = Net(
    n_inputs = 4, # Defined by the number of observables (charge of each channel now).
    n_outputs = 2, # x and y.
    n_hidden_layers = 3, # Choose yourself.
    n_nodes_per_hidden_layer = 66, # Choose yourself.
)
```

My input `x` is data that distributes in a weird way from 0 to 1, my outputs are 2 values in the range 1e-2 +- 100e-6. I have tried `x -= .5` and different scalings too, but cannot make it work. I don't get any error, just it does not seem to learn what it is supposed to learn.

I know that this model should work because I have used it with similar data that distributes in a similar way but the inputs in the range 0-100e-12 using `x *= 1e9` and it was performing reasonably well. I don't know why, however.

Comment: There's so much that can go wrong - splitting data into train/test, enabling gradients, proper scaling of data, how and when you compute gradients, how you call `dnn.train()` and `dnn.eval()`, what loss you're using, optimizers, schedulers, so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

### Data transformation

> They should go between -1 and 1? Between 0 and 1? Can it be anything?

They can be any real valued numbers, but in general we [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) input values using mean and standard deviation (so the result has `0` mean and `1` variance) like this (for two dimensional data that you have, **assuming samples are zeroth dimension and features are the first dimension**):

```
import torch

samples, features = 128, 4
data = torch.randn(samples, features)
std, mean = torch.std_mean(data, dim=0, keepdim=True)

normalized = (data - mean) / std
```

In general neural networks work best with normalized input with similar ranges.

And this transformation could (and should as it will make it easier for `nn.Linear` layer output) also be applied to your regression target as it's reversible.

### Other things

- Use `torch.nn.MSELoss` for regression
- Use standard optimizer (like `Adam`) with default learning rates (you can fine tune it later)
- Make sure your pipeline works correctly

Comment: So I should standarize both inputs and outputs? Why do neural networks prefer normalized data? Because of the nonlinear activation functions?

Comment: Because neural network work on GPUs and those have a limited precision of floating point numbers, if your data is as small as `1e-9`, while weights are about `1e3` you're guaranteed to lose all the precision, and without it you can't compute a meaningful loss, compute a meaningful gradient and thus backpropagate